# Get the only solution based on given constraints using z3 theorem

Tags: python, z3, solver, z3py, reasoning

I have a set of constraints:

```
Lane(l0) == True,
Lane(l1) == True,
OnComingLane(l1) == True,
LaneMarking(m1) == True,
LaneMarking(m0) == True,
SolidWhiteLine(m1) == True,
SolidWhiteLine(m0) == True,
leftConnectedTo(l0, m0) == True,
Driver(v0) == True,
Vehicle(v1) == True,
block(v1, l0) == True,
inFrontOf(v1, v0) == True,
Inoperative(v1) == True,
NotHasOncomingVehicle(l1, v1) == True,
EgoLane(l0) == True
```

and:

```
Implies(
    And(inFrontOf(X, D), Vehicle(X), OnComingLane(Z), SolidWhiteLine(Y),
        leftConnectedTo(G, Y), Driver(D), block(X, G), Inoperative(X),
        NotHasOncomingVehicle(D, Z), EgoLane(G)),
    And(Overtake(X), Cross(Y), LaneChangeTo(Z)))
```

and want to deduce which actions are satisfied:
`{Overtake, Cross, LaneChangeTo}`.
How can I utilize the z3 Theorem for finding the only solution, i.e. `Overtake(v1)`, `Cross(m0)` and `LaneChangeTo(l1)`?

**Extension:**
I still struggle to implement the z3 solver for my problem.
In the implementation, I get as output that for every iteration of all the possible actions the model for `pos-res` and `neg_res` is `SAT` which leads to no valid conclusion. I was wondering, if I made a mistake in the implementation? Or what other approach I could utilize to get the desired output of `Overtake(v1)`, `Cross(m0)` and `LaneChangeTo(l1)`?

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

l0, l1, m1, m0, v1, v0 = Consts('l0 l1 m1 m0 v1 v0', StringSort())

Lane = Function('Lane', StringSort(), BoolSort())
OnComingLane = Function('OnComingLane', StringSort(), BoolSort())
LaneMarking = Function('LaneMarking', StringSort(), BoolSort())
SolidWhiteLine = Function('SolidWhiteLine', StringSort(), BoolSort())
leftConnectedTo = Function('leftConnectedTo', StringSort(), StringSort(), BoolSort())
Driver = Function('Driver', StringSort(), BoolSort())
Vehicle = Function('Vehicle', StringSort(), BoolSort())
block = Function('block', StringSort(), StringSort(), BoolSort())
inFrontOf = Function('inFrontOf', StringSort(), StringSort(), BoolSort())
Inoperative = Function('Inoperative', StringSort(), BoolSort())
NotHasOncomingVehicle = Function('NotHasOncomingVehicle', StringSort(), StringSort(), BoolSort())
EgoLane = Function('EgoLane', StringSort(), BoolSort())
Overtake = Function('Overtake', StringSort(), BoolSort())
Cross = Function('Cross', StringSort(), BoolSort())
LaneChangeTo = Function('LaneChangeTo', StringSort(), BoolSort())

s.add([Lane(l0) == True, Lane(l1) == True, OnComingLane(l1) == True,
       LaneMarking(m1) == True, LaneMarking(m0) == True,
       SolidWhiteLine(m1) == True, SolidWhiteLine(m0) == True,
       leftConnectedTo(l0, m0) == True, Driver(v0) == True,
       Vehicle(v1) == True, block(v1, l0) == True, inFrontOf(v1, v0) == True,
       Inoperative(v1) == True, NotHasOncomingVehicle(l1, v1) == True,
       EgoLane(l0) == True])

X, D, G, Z, Y = Consts('X D G Z Y', StringSort())

rule = ForAll([Y, D, G, Z, X],
           Implies(And(inFrontOf(X, D),
                       Vehicle(X),
                       Inoperative(X),
                       SolidWhiteLine(Y),
                       OnComingLane(Z),
                       leftConnectedTo(G, Y),
                       NotHasOncomingVehicle(D, Z),
                       EgoLane(G),
                       block(X, G),
                       Driver(D)),
                   And(Overtake(X), Cross(Y), LaneChangeTo(Z))))

# overtake_rule = ForAll([X, D], Implies(And(Vehicle(X), Not(Inoperative(X)), Driver(D), inFrontOf(X, D)), Overtake(X)))
# s.add(overtake_rule)
s.add(rule)

actions = [Overtake, Cross, LaneChangeTo]
entities = [l0, l1, m1, m0, v1, v0]

for action in actions:
    for entity in entities:

        s.push()  
        s.add(action(entity) == True)  
        pos_res = s.check()
        model = s.model()
        print(f'pos_res:{pos_res}')
        # print(f'model for pos_res:{model}')
        s.pop()  # Restore the state

        s.push()
        s.add(action(entity) == False)  
        neg_res = s.check()
        model = s.model()
        print(f'neg_res:{neg_res}')
        s.pop()  

        if pos_res == sat and neg_res == unsat:
            print(f"{action}({entity}) is necessarily true.")
        elif pos_res == unsat and neg_res == sat:
            print(f"{action}({entity}) is necessarily false.")
        else:
            print(f"No valid conclusion can be drawn about {action}({entity}).")
```

Comment: It looks like this question was closed a bit too hastily, perhaps due to lack of domain-specific knowledge. It describes the problem with sufficient level of detail to warrant an answer. As a matter of fact, it got one.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to call the solver twice for each conclusion you want. Use the incremental mode. Let's say you added N constraints to the solver, and want to determine if X is necessarily implied. You'd do, in pseudo-code:

```
s.push()
s.add(X)
pos_res = s.check()
s.pop()
s.add(Not(X))
neg_res = s.check()
s.pop()
```

Now do a case analysis on `pos_res` and `neg_res`:

```
pos_res |  neg_res | Conclusion
--------+----------+----------------------------------
  SAT   |     SAT  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
  SAT   |   UNSAT  | X is necessarily true
  SAT   | UNKNOWN  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
--------+----------+----------------------------------
 UNSAT  |     SAT  | X is necessarily false
 UNSAT  |   UNSAT  | Original constraints are conflicting
 UNSAT  | UNKNOWN  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
--------+----------+-----------------------------------
UNKNOWN |     SAT  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
UNKNOWN |   UNSAT  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
UNKNOWN | UNKNOWN  | No valid conclusion can be drawn
```

You can now repeat this for all the constraints you want to check. Of course, you can do this independently; or you can try to see what maximal subset is satisfiable together, for some definition of maximal suitable for your application. (Note that there's no "uniform" definition of maximal in this sense.)

You might also want to look at the `consequences` method, which can provide some automation when applicable. See [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-consequences](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-consequences)

Comment: Thank You for the help! I am still a little bit confused. 
If i try the `neg_res`, `pos_res` method i get `model = sat` for both and when using 's.consequences' it get that no consequence was found. I am still new to the z3 solver and try to get my head around the model creation.