Solving Constraints with Closed World Assumption in Z3 Solver
I am working on a constraint satisfaction problem using the Z3 Solver in Python, where I need to solve a constraint of the form:
ForAll([x, y], Implies(And(situation(x), situation(y)), And(actions(x), actions(y))))

Given a set of facts, such as:
situation(x) == True

I want to apply the closed world assumption, meaning if something is not known to be true, it should be considered false, to find the only possible solution that satisfies both the given facts and the constraint. My goal is to do this without introducing extra information or assumptions beyond what's strictly provided.
I'm currently unsure how to implement the closed world assumption effectively in Z3 to limit the solution space accordingly. Is there a way to instruct Z3 to operate under the closed world assumption directly, or would I need to model this assumption explicitly in my constraints? Any pointers or examples of how to achieve this with Z3 would be greatly appreciated.
Initially, I attempted to manually specify everything not stated as True as False, but this approach proved to be too exhaustive and impractical for my purpose. It significantly increases the complexity and size of the problem without effectively leveraging Z3's capabilities.

SMT solvers do not make closed-world assumptions. They'll respond sat so long as they find a model that satisfies the constraints you presented. For anything that's not explicitly stated, the solver is free to choose an interpretation that makes an arbitrary assignment of truth values.
There's no automatic "switch" to tell z3 (or any other SMT solver) to incorporate the closed-world-assumption. Nor it would be easy to add one, due to their DPLL based architecture. (But perhaps that's besides the point.)
You said "manually adding" the closed-world assumption was too expensive from a modeling perspective. I'm wondering if there might be a different way of modeling that makes the need for a closed-world assumption unnecessary. Remember that while a Prolog like system is essentially atoms and predicates, an SMT solver provides a much richer world: You can have uninterpreted types, enumerated types, etc., that can allow you to solve your problem without the need for a closed-world assumption.
But it is impossible to answer your question in the generality you presented. If you can come up with a simpler concrete example of what you are trying to do, even perhaps showing how you'd do it in Prolog, we might be able to provide you with guidance on how to model it in the world of SMT.
But, long story short, there are no closed-world assumptions in the SMT world. You have to model your problem without having a need for that if you want to leverage SMT solvers.

Thank you for your help! I've already posted my question on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238017/get-the-only-solution-based-on-given-constraints-using-z3-theorem/78239776?noredirect=1#comment137963307_78239776, detailing a constraint and some facts to find a model for Overtake(v1), Cross(m0), and LaneChangeTo(l1). I'm unable to introduce new constraints, only modify existing ones with the given information. My confusion arises from how to gathering a single solution upon setting the facts as true.

Looks like you need closed-world assumption to solve your problem. Then, SMT solvers are just not the right tool for you out-of-the box. You have to enforce the closed-world assumption yourself.  I'd start with a much simpler problem, stop using StringSort extensively and use actual data-types, and post a simpler version of your problem if you're still having issues.
